# Did Heavyweights' Tony Perkis Inspire Dodgeball's White Goodman

Tags: character, dodgeball, heavyweights

In 1995, Ben Stiller started as Tony Perkis in 'Heavyweights'. Tony is a fitness nut who believes he can whip the campers into shape because he too was once fat with low self-esteem.

Similarly, in 2004, Ben Stiller started as White Goodman in 'Dodgeball'. White is a fitness nut who owns Globogym. White, like Tony Perkins in 'Heavyweights', was once fat with low self-esteem.

My Question:

- Did the Dodgeball screenwriter(s) or producers ever admit that Tony Perkis inspired or influenced the development of White Goodman?

Comment: There are quite a lot of theories those are the same person but there is no definite say from writers/directors that it's true. But it's just a trope "ex'fat lazy becomef it hate all fat and lazy" and Stiller might just be good at casting for such roles.

Comment: I did come across an article from some random website that quotes Stiller mentioning a connection between the two characters; but, I wasn't confident enough in the source to use it as a reference in an answer.

Comment: Due to the "Camp Hope Incident", Tony Perkis Jr. changed his name to White Goodman and eventually developed his infomercial product into a string of fitness gyms. The rest is history.